# Systemd mount fails. Where= setting doesn't match unit name

Tags: mount, systemd

If I use this command :

```
mount -t xfs -o noatime,nodiratime,logbufs=8 -L d1 /srv/node/d1
```

all works correctly. But if I try to mount through the `systemd` mount it fails.

I've created a file `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-d1.mount` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description = Disk 1

[Mount]
What = LABEL=d1
Where = /srv/node/d1
Type = xfs
Options = noatime,nodiratime,logbufs=8

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

After that I run these commands:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start mnt-d1.mount
```

The last one showed me:

```
Failed to start mnt-d1.mount: Unit mnt-d1.mount failed to load: Invalid argument.  
See system logs and 'systemctl status mnt-d1.mount' for details.
```

`systemctl status mnt-d1.mount` showed me:

```
May 16 18:13:52 object1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit mnt-d1.mount, ignoring: Unit mnt-d1.mount failed to ...ectory.
May 16 18:24:05 object1 systemd[1]: mnt-d1.mount's Where= setting doesn't match unit name. Refusing.
```

Please help me to mount a disk via a `systemd` mount unit.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The error message explains the cause:

```
Where= setting doesn't match unit name. Refusing.
```

though understanding that message requires reading several man pages.
Per [`systemd.mount` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) (emphasize mine):

> `Where=`
>
> Takes an absolute path of a directory of the mount point. If the mount point does not exist at the time of mounting, it is created.
> **This string must be reflected in the unit filename. (See above.)** This
> option is mandatory.

The "see above" part is:

> Mount units must be named after the mount point directories they
> control. Example: the mount point `/home/lennart` must be configured in
> a unit file `home-lennart.mount`. For details about the escaping logic
> used to convert a file system path to a unit name, see
> `systemd.unit(5)`.

OK, [`systemd.unit` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) states that:

> Properly escaped paths can be generated using the `systemd-escape(1)`
> command.

pointing to [`systemd-escape` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-escape.html) which explains how to do it:

> To generate the mount unit for a path:
>
> `$ systemd-escape -p --suffix=mount "/tmp//waldi/foobar/"`
> `tmp-waldi-foobar.mount`

So, in your case, `/srv/node/d1` translates to `srv-node-d1.mount`

---

Note that **IF PATHS CONTAIN CHARACTERS OTHER THAN** `[[:alnum:]._:]` e.g. punctuation (except the three mentioned before), spaces etc, those characters will be replaced by their ASCII hex code (e.g `\x20` for space) so the resulting escaped path might contain backslashes:

```
systemd-escape -p --suffix=mount '/media/offline@server/<user>'
```

outputs

```
media-offline\x40server-\x3cuser\x3e.mount
```

Now that might need an additional level of escaping when used in terminal or scripts. I recommend single-quoting the whole string and be done with it:

```
touch '/etc/systemd/system/media-offline\x40server-\x3cuser\x3e.mount'
```

but you can also escape all backslashes if you so wish, see [mrhhug's post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/657413) below.

Comment: It's important to note that the "path escaping" system can get a bit complex even dealing with non-A-Z names. Even some dashes in the path will need to be converted to the C-style `\x2d` escape, which when used to create the unit file may (depending on your shell/editor) need to again escape the slash character - so the unit file fit mounting `/some-path` may require running `edit some\\x2dpath.mount`

Comment: I ended up here trying to figure out why I couldn't mount `share-name`. Renaming it `share_name` solved the problem.

Comment: I'd give a double upvote if I could!

Comment: Why is it so ridiculously hard to have a unit file for mounting a path with a `-` character? I generated the mount with `systemd-escape -p --suffix=mount "/storage/media-server"` and it output `storage-media\x2dserver.mount` and that filename still produces the same error..

Comment: How are spaces escaped in the `Where=`? Neither \x20 nor quotes seemed to work for me.

Comment: It's important to remember that the shell will grab the escape sequence first and replace it, as mentioned above, so it's necessary to escape the escape sequence so that the shell allows it through. However when doing things that are not in the shell, for example inside a unit file, do not escape twice in that situation. Mixing this up will cause it to not work, in an especially confusing way.

Do not escape the contents of the `Where=` clause.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is seeing this error when trying to mount in a local directory that contains a hyphen, be careful when you address that file on your shell, my shell (bash 4) needed the slash escaped, so we are escaping the escape. 
Example:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/mnt-my\x2dlocal\x2ddir.mount
[Unit]
Description=My mount

[Mount]
What=//some/remote/share
Where=/mnt/my-local-dir
Type=cifs
Options=user=nonrootuser

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The absolute file path in this example is :
`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-my\x2dlocal\x2ddir.mount`

but to rename your file you need to do this :

```
mv /my/original/file /etc/systemd/system/mnt-my\\x2dlocal\\x2ddir.mount
```

and when you call systemd you need to

```
systemctl status /etc/systemd/system/mnt-my\\x2dlocal\\x2ddir.mount
```

Now you can mount remote shares at boot as a non-root user.

Answer (score 0):

## Keys to success

In addition to what others have said, here's a few things that may not have been clear enough:

1. Keys like `What=` and `Where=` have literal values - no escapes
2. Paths on the filesystem must be `systemd-escape`d

   - the shell will interpret `\`, so SINGLE quote it to escape: `'my\x20'`
3. You MUST run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` between name/content changes
4. `sudo journalctl -xe ESCAPEME.mount` will give better logs that `status`

### Example: /etc/systemd/system/ESCAPEME.mount

`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-TrueNAS-TV\x20Shows.mount`:

```
[Unit]
  Description=My CIFs Media Mounter
  Requires=network-online.target
  After=network-online.service

[Mount]
  What=//192.168.1.200/TV Shows
  Where=/mnt/TrueNAS/TV Shows
  Options=username=my-user,password=my-secret
  Type=cifs

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Example: /etc/systemd/system/ESCAPEME.automount

`/etc/systemd/system/mnt-TrueNAS-TV\x20Shows.automount`:

```
[Unit]
  Description=My CIFs Media Automount

[Automount]
  Where=/mnt/TrueNAS/TV Shows

[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to the example in this question,
but this may help others who get the same error:

You CANNOT add a comment on the same line as an assignment
(that will be part of the variable).

So, if your file says

```
Where=/here # Mount it there
```

it will try to mount "`/here # Mount it there`" ... and not `/here`.