# fstab mount wait for network

Tags: networking, mount

I'm trying to mount a CIFS device after the system boots (using `systemd`), but the system tries to mount the system before the network is established, so it fails.

After logging into the system I can mount it without any problem, using `sudo mount -a`.

How can I tell my Arch (arm) to wait until the network is available?

Comment: There's a similar question about this, please see [mount samba shares at boot with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292452/).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Adding `_netdev` to the mount options in `/etc/fstab` might be sufficient.

> Mount units referring to local and network file systems are distinguished by their file system type specification. In some cases this is not sufficient (for example network block device based mounts, such as iSCSI), in which case _netdev may be added to the mount option string of the unit, which forces systemd to consider the mount unit a network mount.

Additionally `systemd` supports explicit order dependencies between mount entries and other units: Adding `x-systemd.after=network-online.target` to the mount options might work if _netdev is not enough.

See [the systemd mount unit documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) for more details.

Comment: the *_netdev* section did not work for me BUT it was left and the *x-systemd.after=network-online.target*  did on nfsv4 mounts, this was verifed on U16.04.6 vm

Comment: @ssvegeta96 yeah, i have never in my life seen that _netdev works on systemd. they just don't care enough. (not to mention that needing any of that is a regression compared to classic unix which simply sorted the fstab from local to non-local)

Comment: careful: having `nofail` disables the automatic addition of `x-systemd.after...` targets (cf same doc page), so you have to add them explicitly

Answer (score 8):

Add `_netdev` to the `/etc/fstab` entries in question.  From the manpages for `mount(8)':

> _netdev
>                The  filesystem  resides  on  a  device  that requires network
>                access (used to prevent the system from  attempting  to  mount
>                these  filesystems  until  the network has been enabled on the
>                system).

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky, but all _netdev and x-systemd options didn't help, since WINS/DNS was stil not running.
I got going with a root crontab entry:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/mount -a
```

This is run late in the boot process.
So even if systemd fails in the first place to mount the CIFS mount defined in fstab, later a `mount -a` is run again and this time the mount succeeds.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fighting systemd assumptions and legacy options which may or may not work, make your service and make your mount target depend on it.

My SMB shares are mounted from 192.168.1.2, change to what is correct in your case.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/wait-for-ping.service
[Unit]
Description=Blocks until it successfully pings 192.168.1.2
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c "while ! ping -c1 192.168.1.2; do sleep 1; done"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo good to go"
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable that service with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable --now wait-for-ping.service
```

Then edit your fstab as follows to include this as final mount option:

```
x-systemd.after=wait-for-ping.service
```

Do another `systemctl daemon-reload` and you can verify that your mount target has the correct option set. My mount target is `/mnt/media`, that creates `mnt-media.mount`, so do:

`systemctl cat mnt-media.mount`

This should have an header like this:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
After=wait-for-ping.service

# ... rest of file follows ...
```

Reboot your machine and you should find your mounts waiting until a ping succeeds.

Comment: Works very fine on Debian 12.