# (Ubuntu 19.04) NFS share won't automount at boot: 'mount.nfs: Network is unreachable'

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, mount, automounting

I cannot figure out how to mount an NFS share at boot.  I've tried a couple different things (listed below) and nothing has worked.  In both instances, they require `network-online.target`, yet they don't seem to be waiting for the network to be online before starting.  Yes, I can indeed communicate with the remote machine, and I can run `mount -a` after logging in and the shares will mount.  I'm at a complete loss.

**Attempt #1**:
I put the following in `/etc/fstab`:

```
10.0.10.10:/volume1/Media /mnt/media nfs x-systemd.automount,noauto,nofail,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,suid,dev,exec,rw,sync,nouser 0 0
```

The result after rebooting:

```
root@ubuntu-svr:~# journalctl -b -u mnt-media.mount
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-08-12 00:00:56 UTC, end at Fri 2019-09-20 22:05:16 UTC. --
Sep 20 21:36:29 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: Mounting Mounts the '/mnt/media' directory...
Sep 20 21:36:29 ubuntu-svr mount[1528]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Sep 20 21:36:29 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Sep 20 21:36:29 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 20 21:36:29 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mounts the '/mnt/media' directory.
```

**Attempt #2**:  I commented out the fstab entry and created a systemd mnt-media.mount file and enabled the systemd unit to start on boot.  This is what the `mnt-media.mount` file consisted of:

```
root@ubuntu-svr:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/mnt-media.mount
[Unit]
Description=Mounts the '/mnt/media' directory
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=network-online.target
#After=network-online.target

[Mount]
Where=/mnt/media
What=10.0.10.10:/volume1/Media
Options=auto,x-systemd.automount,nofail,suid,dev,exec,rw,sync,nouser
Type=nfs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I enabled it via `systemctl enable mnt-media.mount`.  I rebooted, and checked the status of it:

```
root@ubuntu-svr:~# systemctl status mnt-media.mount
● mnt-media.mount - Mounts the '/mnt/media' directory
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-media.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-09-20 22:28:51 UTC; 1min 12s ago
    Where: /mnt/media
     What: 10.0.10.10:/volume1/Media

Sep 20 22:28:51 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: Mounting Mounts the '/mnt/media' directory...
Sep 20 22:28:51 ubuntu-svr mount[1206]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
Sep 20 22:28:51 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Sep 20 22:28:51 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: mnt-media.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 20 22:28:51 ubuntu-svr systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mounts the '/mnt/media' directory.
```

Comment: Take a look at autofs. It won't mount anything shares until they're actually used. Not sure why it's trying to mount before the network is up; my Samba mounts don't have this issue.

Comment: This might also help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349264/fstab-mount-wait-for-network

Comment: @ajgringo619 -- I looked into autofs, but I need it to mount before they're even used because docker I have docker containers that autostart that rely on this share.

I checked out that link earlier -- that's how I came up with my fstab entry.

Comment: @beechfuzz Can you try setting the 'after network-online.target' option? If that works out, you could then modify the Docker unit file to have a dependency on this mount point.

Comment: I figured it out -- I submitted the answer.  I needed to enable `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`.  I had previously disabled it to speed up boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved:**

Turns out I needed to enabled the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` service.  Now both attempts that I tried (/etc/fstab and mnt-media.mount) work as intended.

For anyone else struggling with this, depending on whether you're using `systemd-networkd` or `NetworkManager`, you need to make sure that `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` or `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` is enabled on your system.  Otherwise, your system will not wait for the network to be up even though your mounts explicitly require it.

I came across this answer via this link: [NFS/Troubleshooting - Network is unreachable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS/Troubleshooting#mount.nfs4:_Network_is_unreachable).

Comment: this needs to be run on the server or the client

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not help you i.e me (had the services already enabled and running NetMan)

I added **x-systemd.after=network-online.target** to the **fstab** entry and rebooted and it worked. not sure if the **_netdev** helps but its part of my entry aswell.