# Trying to use NFS

Tags: networking, fedora, filesystems

Finally shut down my Linux Cent OS Server.

Set up a new Fedora 36 Plex server. All set up, but ran into a problem.

I can’t get the Fedora PC to connect automatically with the file system on my NAS.

If I do a manualy

`sudo mount -t nfs 10.0.10.4:/Library/Extras /media/shares`

It works.

However, put the line in /etc/fstab

`10.0.10.4:/Library/Extras /media/shares nfs4 auto,defaults 0 0`

NOPE… WILL NOT WORK NO MATTER WHAT.

I’ve been using this for over 5+ years this way with a separate plex server, and files on a NAS unit… What changed that you can’t use NFS anymore in Fedora??

Thanks to anyone who knows.

Comment: When it "will not work", what exactly does it do or not do?

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
10.0.10.4:/Library/Extras /media/shares nfs auto,defaults 0 0
```

work in `/etc/fstab`? Note the change to `nfs` from `nfs4`.

Comment: no, I tried this one first.

Comment: @Borg357 please update your question to show what you tried. This is most definitely the obvious solution so you need to be clear - in your question - that you had already tried this and it didn't work. Ideally dig through `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/daemon.log` (i.e. one of the system log files) and see if you can identify the reported reason for the failure.

Comment: Perhaps adding some more mount options, like in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349278) might work?