# Prevent systemd from unmounting a partition mounted by a systemd service

Tags: shell-script, systemd, mount, automounting, unmounting

I have a custom systemd service that automatically mounts some partitions under certains conditions. The service executes a shell script containing some mount commands. When I execute it directly, everything works fine and the partitions stay mounted even after the shell script returns. But when I start it with systemd, the partitions are mounted, but they get automatically unmounted after that the shell script returns. How can I keep them mounted?

My custom systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Automatically mount secondary volumes

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/opt/vmount
ExecStart=/opt/vmount/vmount.sh
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I am seeing this problem too, with a backup script running on a systemd timer. In my case I want the disk unmounted once the script stops, but if I call `systemctl stop`, the disk is unmounted *before* my backup script can handle the SIGTERM and do its own cleanup. So that is undesirable. Very interested if you ever solved it!

Comment: What do you run in the `vmount.sh`?

Comment: @ChrisBillington : Could this answer from Poettering himself help you to understand better what happens and how to workaround this issue ? : https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5669#issuecomment-290363903

Comment: @MC68020 I don't think this applies - this is an opposite situation mount via bash and it gets automatically unmounted when the script ends. In general mounting a volume via systemd & bash script is weird.  I can't imagine a workflow where this is needed.

Comment: @tukan, my workflow is that I'm doing backups to a different disk for each weekday, and it's easier to do the logic of which disk to mount from within Python code than to try to figure out how to describe this in terms of systemd units. And it's just unexpected - if I didn't ask systemd itself to do the mounting, I didn't expect it to unmount unconditionally. I'm yet to find even a description of this as intended behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisBillington if you have such workflow then you can follow the logic I have provided in my answer nad have a `.mount` unit for everyday, which would point to a mount point of your choosing.  Then you could use systemd timers to mount them. As for the mount, it depends what is actually done within the mount (is it a usb drive, networkdrive, etc).  The systemd is wrong facility for automounting if you plugin drives that should be done via udev rules.

Comment: @ChrisBillington are you possibly mounting filesystem types that are implemented in userspace like FUSE does? e.g. ntfs-3g, sshfs, and many others?

Comment: @LL3 Yes, I am mounting an NTFS filesystem. Does that mean my backup script is spawning a subprocess for the mount or something, and systemd is sending that process SIGTERM at the same time as it does the main process? I do see output from ntfs-3g in the journal for my service upon the mount and unmount commands, which confuses me unless it's a subprocess.

Comment: @tukan, these are USB hard drives, if that makes a difference. Thanks for the info about timers. It makes sense, it's just a little overcomplicated compared to the script itself doing the mounting and unmounting. The partitions should be unmounted other than when the backup is running, so I don't want them to be automounted generally.

Comment: @ChrisBillington Yes, it likely does mean that. Your script runs `mount`, which in turn spawns a `fusermount` process as per FUSE normal behavior. That process lives until an explicit `unmount` or until it gets killed some way. By default such process belongs to the same control-group assigned to your script by systemd. You can double-check that using `systemd-cgls`. Default systemd behavior for stopping a `simple` service such as the one in OP is to kill the entire control-group, see `systemd.kill(5)`. There are ways for you to fix your use case, depending on your overall setup.

Comment: @LL3, amazing, that makes much more sense. That should point me in the right direction. In my case I do want the disk unmounted upon SIGTERM, but not until after the script does some cleanup, so I'll look into what options I have to delay or prevent systemd killing the subprocess so I can do it explicitly after cleanup. Thanks so much for clarifying what's happening!

Comment: @LL3, looks like I need to set `KillMode=mixed` and OP needs to set `KillMode=process` (or better: follow @tukan's answer). I can't test yet as I don't have access to the relevant system, but given my understanding now, I'm confident that's it.

Comment: @ChrisBillington I can confirm that in a case that is tangentially similar to the OP's, `KillMode=process` works perfectly. Thanks for being persistent and figuring this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is hidden in the sh/bash script.  This is not the proper way to mount a volume via systemd.

The following way is the systemd's way to persistent mounting:

create:
`vim /etc/systemd/system/mnt-backup.mount`

with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=proper mounting with systemd

[Mount]
What=/dev/sdc1
Where=/mnt/backup
Type=ext4

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To mount the volume simply start it:
`systemctl start mnt-backup.mount`

Next check its systemd state:
`systemctl status mnt-backup.mount`

And check if it was actually mounted with `mount`.

To make it persistent:

`systemctl enable mnt-backup.mount`

*Note:* All commands should be executed as root, if you use `sudo` instead you need to prefix all command in the shell with it.

Comment: Unit name _must_ match the mount point [otherwise you'll get an error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283442)

Comment: @don_crissti good point, fixed.